# Why is this setState not causing a rerender?

Tags: reactjs

I display different Nav paths depending on the type of user that is logged in.

Some code:

```
const celeb = localStorage.getItem("celeb");
const [navPath, setNavPath] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
    const path = celeb == "true" ? "dashboard" : "requests";

    setNavPath(path);
}, []);
```

the celeb returned from above is either "true" or "false" (string btw).

in the useEffect, I set the `navPath` to "dashboard" if the celeb is true, and if the celeb is `not true` I set the `navPath` to 'requests'.

here is my navigation stats:

```
const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState([
    { name: "Catogories", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Home", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "How does it work", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Celebs", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "About", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: navPath, href: navPath, current: false },
 ]);
```

On first Render the `navPath` logs empty, but on the second it logs either `request` or `dashboard`. The problem is that when the navPath is set to a new value, it doesn't cause a render, so I have reload to see the changes.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You need another `useEffect` to update `navigation`.

```
useEffect(() => setNavigation([...defaultNavigation, { name: navPath, href: navPath, current: false }]), [navPath]);
```

Full code

```
const App = () => {
  const celeb = localStorage.getItem("celeb");
  const defaultNavigation = [
    { name: "Catogories", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Home", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "How does it work", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Celebs", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "About", href: "#", current: false },
  ];
  const [navPath, setNavPath] = useState("");
  const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState([...defaultNavigation, { name: navPath, href: navPath, current: false }]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const path = celeb == "true" ? "dashboard" : "requests";
    setNavPath(path);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => setNavigation([...defaultNavigation, { name: navPath, href: navPath, current: false }]), [navPath]);
  return navigation.map(({ name, href, current }) => (
    ...
  ));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect hook in your code is not causing a re-render because it only runs once after the initial rendering of the component due to its dependency array being empty ([]). This means it will not respond to changes in celeb because celeb is not included in the dependency array.
To solve this issue, you could move the fetching of celeb into the useEffect hook and include celeb in the dependency array. However, because localStorage is not reactive, changes to it won't trigger a re-render of the component. Instead, you could listen for changes to localStorage using an event listener. Here's an example

```
useEffect(() => {
 function checkCelebData() {
   const celeb = localStorage.getItem('celeb');

   if (celeb) {
     const path = celeb == "true" ? "dashboard" : "requests";
     setNavPath(path);
   }
 }

 window.addEventListener('storage', checkCelebData);

 return () => {
   window.removeEventListener('storage', checkCelebData);
 }
}, []);
```